# In Google Sheets, pause formula calculation until Apps Script has completed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a situation in which I have two separate Spreadsheets (let's call them 1 and 2). In 1, I import a specific sheet from 2 using a script that copies the sheet from 2 and pastes an exact duplicate in 1. I used to use IMPORTRANGE, but the formula itself was unreliable (the sheet from 2 is quite large).

My problem is that in 1, there is another sheet that references the imported sheet from 2 using several complex arrayformulas. When I run the script to import the data from 2, it takes a very long time because the arrayformulas continue calculating while the data is importing from 2. Then once the data is imported, those arrayformulas recalculate again.

Is there any way to run the entire script and prevent Sheets from calculating the arrayformulas until the script completes? Open to other ideas as well.

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a generic "pause calculation" function, but in your case you could remove the arrayformulas before writing the data, then re-write them to the sheet afterward.  (Store them first using .getFormulas(), then call .clearContent(), then write them back using .setFormulas())

Comment: That's a great idea. I will try it out. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: the "duplicate" question is more general (for which the answer is "no"), but this question describes a specific situation where a workaround may be viable.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee I think your answer would equally apply to that question as well.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee Your idea to .getFormulas(), then .clearContent(), then .setFormulas() did the trick. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that might work.

For your formulas, wrap the IMPORTRANGE with IFERROR and then have a trigger like IF(ISBLANK(...) for your other formulas. Reference a cell further down in your dataset (e.g. A200) that will be nonblank if your initial IMPORTRANGE completed properly.

Let me know if that makes sense.